# SQL Server Get Date Field if less than 3 month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just need a where condition in my select statement where AddedDate is less than or within the 3 month backet. Like

```
Select * FROM My Table where AddedDate DateDiff of DateNow less than 3 months
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [**DATEADD()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
Select * FROM My Table where AddedDate>=DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: m = Months, -3 = -3 Months. Therefore value will be the current date, -3 months

Comment: No, it says AddedDate >= 2011-10-30

Comment: Yeah sweet that's all good thanks that's what i was looking for since you answered first i'll mark you as answered.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  AddedDate >= DATEADD(month, -3, getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

not entirely sure that I understand but I think this is the function you need

```
where AddedDate >= dateadd(mm, -3,  getdate())
```